# Do humans emit any energy that can be measured through the fingertips?

Tags: energy, electricity, temperature, thermal-radiation, biophysics

I am doing a bit of experimentation in touchscreen, and from my science classes I am pretty sure I remember being told that humans emit some sort of energy, I'v been researching this, and found Magnetic Induction, not sure if this is actually a thing in humans, and electric waves, I would really appreciate some correct info on this!

I plan to use this touchscreen, or what ever it should be called, for silent buttons on keyboards.

Answer (score 3):

> Do humans emit any energy that can be measured through the fingertips?

Put the finger tips of one hand very close to, but not touching, your lips. Do you feel warmth? You are emitting infra red radiation, the same radiation that police helicopters use at night to track burglers,  car thieves etc.

[image]

Infrared map of a human face

But you do not need to **emit** anything to operate touchscreens.

[image]

Source: [Touchscreens](http://www.explainthatstuff.com/touchscreens.html)

> These screens are made from multiple layers of glass. The inner layer conducts electricity and so does the outer layer, so effectively the screen behaves like two electrical conductors separated by an insulator—in other words, a capacitor. When you bring your finger up to the screen, you alter the electrical field by a certain amount that varies according to where your hand is. Capacitive screens can be touched in more than one place at once. Unlike most other types of touchscreen, they don't work if you touch them with a plastic stylus (because the plastic is an insulator and stops your hand from affecting the electric field).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the human body emits biophotons, also known as ultra-weak photon emissions (UPE), with a visibility 1,000 times lower than the sensitivity of our naked eye. While not visible to us, these particles of light (or waves, depending on how you are measuring them) are part of the visible electromagnetic spectrum (380-780 nm) and are detectable via sophisticated modern instrumentation.

Answer (score 0):

As KC sais humans emit photons continiously, and also balckbody infrared radiation. But from what i've seen in wikipedia, touchscreen either detect the presure of your finger when you touch the screen or use you finger as a conductor to close a small circuit, or charge a small capacitor that will discharge when you touch it, as your body can absorb electricity, leaving it on ground. Hope you got her your answer :) No human 'energy' involved